# router-outlet' is not a known element: add CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas'

Tags: router-outlet

-->

I want routing and if I comment router-outlet then it is working otherwise it is not working give solution fast

I want to resolve this error but its taking error give me solution as soon as possible I want to know why its taking error if everything is correct